# Flask-limiter - add custom key name in redis

Tags: python, redis, rate-limiting, flask-limiter

How can I change the key name stored in Redis by Flask-limiter?

https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a key prefix

```
limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["200 per day", "50 per hour"],
    storage_uri='redis://localhost:6379',
    key_prefix='DTM',
)
```

This changes the keyname from

```
LIMITER/127.0.0.1/slow/1/1/day
```

to

```
LIMITER/DTM/127.0.0.1/slow/1/1/day
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the response by namizaru: you can only control some parts of the key with this library.

Given the example from namizaru:

```
LIMITER/127.0.0.1/slow/1/1/day
```

The string "LIMITER" comes from the limits library (https://github.com/alisaifee/limits), which Flask-limiter wraps. I don't see a good way to override this.

"127.0.0.1" is the result of the `key_func` parameter passed to `Limiter` (`get_remote_address`) and should return a unique string that identifies the rate-limited resource, as far as I understand. So, you can provide your own callable there, but that only changes one portion of the key.

Meanwhile, the delimiter ("/") also comes from the limits library and does not seem overridable.